# Rails 3.2.9 is generating a Template Missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error in Rails 3.2.9:

`Template is missing`

`Missing template projects/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Documents and Settings/.../app/views"`

I started getting this error yesterday, went back and rebuilt my controller and was still getting the error.  I then rebuilt everything with the `rails generate scaffold` on the command line.  When I went in to save a new object instance, I am still getting the same error.

My presumption is that the scaffold generator would produce the correct code on a bare-bones basis, and then allow me to piece by piece, rebuild the functionality.

I am including the code for the model and controller below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible   :title, ...

end
```

++++++++++

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /projects
  def index
    @projects = Project.all


  end

  # GET /projects/1
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])


  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new


  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /projects
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    @project.save

  end

  # PUT /projects/1
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])


  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy


  end
end
```

Anyone have any ideas?  Did Rails develop a bug overnight?  I haven't been able to find anything using Google-Fu that might attribute to this.
Thanks.

Comment: Your `create` action isn't rendering or redirecting, so it's assumed you intend for it to render a `create` view. Rails can't find one. The code you've posted wouldn't have ever worked in any recent version of Rails. It also doesn't appear to have been output by the scaffolding generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about default rails scaffolding in rails but in general you should redirect on create with a success flash message:

```
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
if @project.save
  redirect_to @project, notice: "Success"
else
  render :new
end
```